# Css pointer-events hover issue

Tags: css, hover

I have to following code:

```
<div class="playlist-item">
  <a class="playlist-non-selected" href="#">
    <span class="playlist-title">AudioAgent - Japanese Intro</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4uyb7rh9/10/

The problem is when you rollover the text, in firefox and ie overPlaylistItem & outPlaylistItem are constantly called and cursor just keeps flickering. This works properly in chrome. Is there a way to make this work in all browsers?

Comment: Remove the `pointer-events: none`. Don't understand why it is even there?

Comment: I know this causes the issue, but I need this, because when playlist item is clicked (and gets playlist-selected class on click), I append something inside it and I dont want to be clickable any more (until it gets playlist-non-selected class).

Comment: Then you need to add that "something" as well so we have the full picture, or else what we suggest might fail

Comment: I dont want javascript change, I was wondering is this some kind of css quirk.

Comment: I updated my answer with an update of your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because when you set the class having `pointer-events: none` it triggers a mouse leave event, hence it flashes.

First of all, may I suggest you use `:hover`, second, whether you use `:hover` or script, you need to target the specific element that shouldn't be clickable, for example the `span`

```
.playlist-non-selected:hover span {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
.playlist-item {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.playlist-title {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'Gnuolane Free';
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.playlist-non-selected {
  color: #bbb;
}
.playlist-non-selected:hover{
  color: red;
}
.playlist-non-selected:hover span{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="playlist-item">
  <a class="playlist-non-selected" href="#">
    <span class="playlist-title">AudioAgent - Japanese Intro</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

---

And here is [an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4uyb7rh9/15/) using your script

---

*Update based on comment about not working in Edge*

Appears to be some kind of bug in Edge when the `span` has `display: block` so changing it to `display: inline-block` and it works.

For it to work in IE11, the `span` need `display: inline` (or just remove the `display:...`) so it use its default.

---

*Update 2 based on comment about not working in Edge*

If you need the `span` to display as block, changing it to a `div` and it works in both Edge and IE11.

[An updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4uyb7rh9/16/) using your script

Comment: I need javascript for mouse enter/leave because of other actions, but adding pointer-events: none; to span does solve the problem.

Comment: @Toniq Wasn't aware it didn't work in Edge ... will have a look later and let you know.

Comment: @Toniq Update my answer, appears to be some kind of bug in Edge when the span is displayed as block, so changing it to `display: inline-block` and it work ... IE11 need `display: inline`

Comment: @LGSon Thank you. It works for me but with `:active` event not `:hover`

Answer (score 1):

Why haven't you used `:hover` ? This can be done with CSS easily and will not pose any difficulty for browsers compatability  like

```css
.playlist-item {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.playlist-title {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'Gnuolane Free';
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  backface-visibility:hidden
}

.playlist-non-selected:hover{
  color: red;
  pointer-events: none;
  backface-visibility:hidden
}

.playlist-non-selected {
  color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div class="playlist-item">
  <a class="playlist-non-selected" href="#">
    <span class="playlist-title">AudioAgent - Japanese Intro</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @LGSon You are saying :hover does not works in FF. I can not believe it. Wait for some time... I will post a screen shot

Comment: No, I'm saying it doesn't work any different than what OP already posted using script, so when hovered in FF, the text start to blink

Comment: I tested your update in FF and the text/color still flashes. Don't you see that too?